# Scala difference between "+:" and "::"

Tags: scala

I am reading a scala book and they use two different type of cons operators when doing pattern matching on sequences and lists

```
+:

::
```

usually most functional languages use `::` as cons. I don't know why scala has 2 different type of operators for the cons.

I googled on the this as well ... but didn't find anything meaningful.

Thanks for the answer below. I understood from it that `+:` is a generic operator and `::` is specific for lists. But my perhaps a follow up question is why would scala use two operators. why not just use one `::`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

and

```
override def +:[B >: A, That](elem: B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That = bf match {
  case _: List.GenericCanBuildFrom[_] => (elem :: this).asInstanceOf[That]
  case _ => super.+:(elem)(bf)
}
```

that makes it clear - **::** takes List and produces List, while **+:** is more generic form, that can build other collections - like **Vector** or **ArrayBuffer**.

Comment: but why to have 2? most other functional languages just have `::` and it can handle both list and vector and array buffer. What was the need to have one specialized form for lists and other more generic form for vectors and arraybuffers?

Comment: "most other functional languages just have :: and it can handle both list and vector and array buffer" — I'm skeptical that's true. what language(s) do you have in mind?

Comment: I have coded a bit in F# (which I believe is very similar to OCAML). and from what I remember I always used `::`. I am no expert...

Answer (score 4):

as for your follow-up question `::` is more of a legacy from earlier Scala implementation which tried to have a similar syntex with existing functional languages.
Use `+:` which is more consistent.